# jquery datatables custom filters

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, datatables, yajra-datatable

I'm using jquery datatables with version 1.10.12. I'm using dropdown to filters rows in datatables. I have server endpoints which returns data in json form (thanks to [yajrabox](http://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master) for laravel). My question is how can I load new data into my existing instance
Here is my code

```
var candidateDT = $("#candidates").DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: '{!! url("/admin/candidates") !!}',
        });

$(".filters").on('click', function(){
            var url = '{{ url("admin/candidates/filters") }}';
            var filterby = $(this).data('filter-by');
            var value = $(this).val();
            if(value !== ""){
                $.ajax({
                    url:url,
                    data: {'filterby':filterby, 'value':value},
                    success: function(response) {
                        candidateDT.clear();
                        candidateDT.reload();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Where url is my endpoint for data source, and filters is my dropdown
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can destroy and recreate datatable that would be easy to use filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is with Ajax you can send more parameter to access from back-end. So you can try following way:

```
$("#candidates").DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: {
        url: '{!! url("/admin/candidates") !!}',
        type: "get",
        data: function(f) {
            f.varname = $("#field").val(); //here place
        }
    },
});
```